# Compare two rows on the google spreadsheet django

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a problem on right now.
I have a google spreadsheet that is responses of the questionnaire.I want to count how many men score points(5,4,3,2,1 points) for the traffic of this place and so do women.
like this.[image] How can I do ?By the way I used google api on django

```
#All responses save in data  
data = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())
#get data of traffic
data['trafic']
#['5','4','3','4','2']

#get data of gender
data['gender']
#['woman','man','woman','woman','man']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be to go over the arrays and sum up the contents depending on what you encounter.

**Example**

```
sum_men = 0
sum_women = 0
for i in range(0, len(data['traffic'])):
    if data['gender'][i] == "man":
        sum_men += data['traffic'][i]
    else:
        sum_women += data['traffic'][i]

print sum_men, sum_women
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It really helps me. Thanks a lot